# Visibility between spring:beans vs spring:bean in Spring XML config

Tags: spring, mule

I am using Mule/ Spring XML to define a set of spring beans.

I can create a bean using the following xml without wraping them in spring:beans element like so:

```
<spring:bean id="myFactoryBean" class="org.test.MyFactoryBean" />
```

But If I try referencing another bean it doesn't work unless I wrap both beans in the same spring beans:element like so:

```
<spring:beans>
     <spring:bean id="myFactoryBean" class="org.test.MyFactoryBean" />

        <spring:bean id="MyBean" class="org.test.MyBean" c:factory-ref="myFactoryBean" />
</spring:beans>
```

Why do I have to wrap them for them to have visibilty of each other? Is this a generic Spring XML requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `c` namespace is only recognized under the scope of the `spring:beans` element. The same applies to the `p` namespace and all other Spring namespaces, like `context` or `util`.

If you replace `c:factory-ref` with a classic `constructor` argument, it should work even if the `spring:bean`s are not wrapped by a `spring:beans` element.

But, I personally recommend as good practice, to always have your `spring:bean`s in a `spring:beans` wrapper element. It keeps then neatly organized and enables all Spring namespaces.